# asp.net cookie secure failing on localhost

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, cookies

I am trying to make asp.net cookie secure like `Response.Cookies["username"].Secure = true`. Some reason these are failing. I mean after login I am setting this then new page is showing error `"Page can not displyed"`.

`Response.Cookies["username"].HttpOnly= true` is working for all cookies. not `Secure`.

Is it because I am using on localhost? does it need `https://`?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: make all cookies secure and httponly? I added samething web.config file still now working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Secure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.secure(v=vs.110).aspx) property of an HttpCookie means that the cookie is only transmitted over SSL. So to test it you need to self-generate a certificate and have your site respond to https requests as well.